# How to make option required in Microsoft's CommandLineUtils?

Tags: c#, command-line, .net-core

In recent years Microsoft has introduced command line processing tools for .NET core apps. Here's the article describing them - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763239.aspx .

Basically we have options, and commands:

```
Usage:  [options] [command]
Options:
  -$|-g |--greeting <greeting>  The greeting to display. 
                                The greeting supports a format string 
                                where {fullname} will be substituted 
                                with the full name.
  -u | --uppercase              Display the greeting in uppercase.
  -? | -h | --help              Show help information
Commands:
  name 
Use " [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

To handle input we must create the instance of `CommandLineApplication` class, and configure options, and commands. Then we run  `commandLineApplication.Execute(args);` (where args are console application parameters, which is `string[] args`), and it works.

Until it doesn't.

The problem is that there's only rather vague documentation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.commandlineutils.commandlineapplication?view=aspnetcore-1.1)  . Either the tools are very simple either the documentation miss few things.

My question is - does anybody know is it possible to make the option required? If it is how to do it then?

Also - how to handle empty options? Unfortunately so far if we run the application like that: `commandApp.exe -g` we will get just the exception (before the app goes into `.onExecute` handler, which is even worse than the exception itself).

Comment: The code is not difficult to understand, https://github.com/aspnet/Common/tree/dev/shared/Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Sources/CommandLine Note that this library will no longer grow much. Microsoft won't pursue it, and start a new one, https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/issues/1311